# How to set two different jre in two different eclipse in window 7 machine

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working in two different project and both the projects are running in two different java (jdk6 and jdk 8) version in eclispe kepler .

Therefore i need to set the java in both the projects , so have a compile class file in same java version.

I can use two different eclipse kepler for this.

Installed java is jdk 6.

Thanks is advance for help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S5xeXawYgK0

Answer (score 0):

In Preferences, go to "Installed JREs", add both JREs there.
Then use different workspaces for each project.

Comment: **Thanks Moritz** Can you please tell me how to add two JREs . Currently there is one jre6 and path is **C:\Program Files\Java\jre6**. now, I am in pop-up asking for  **Enter the home directory of the JRE.**

Comment: @San87 You will need to have a Java 8 install somewhere that you can specify in the Add JRE dialog. Note that Java 6 is very old and no longer updated, you really should try to move to a newer Java.